# Analysis, matrix exponential, infimum and limit

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

I was working in this problem for a long time and I didn't have success.

Someone could help me, please?

The problem:

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n^2} \times \mathbb{Z}^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
f(X,z) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} |x_i^{T} z|,
$$
where $x_i^{T}$ is the $i$-th row of $X$.

My question is:
If $f(e^{X}B, z) = 0 \iff z = 0  \;(B \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2})$ is it true that
$$
\inf_{z \neq 0} \lim_{X \rightarrow 0} f(e^{X}B, z) = \lim_{X \rightarrow 0} \inf_{z \neq 0} f(e^{X}B, z) ?
$$
Remark:

1. $e^{X} = \exp(X)= \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{X^{k}}{k!}$ is infinitely differentiable.
2. $B$ is a full rank matrix. In my problem this is a matrix of lattice for me.
3. $X$ is an antisymmetric matrix. I can see with the hypothesis of the problem the matrix $X$ converges to zero. For my propose I used it because the exponential of antisymmetric is an orthogonal matrix. I think that I don't add this hypothesis in this question. But I worked with matrices $X$ antysymetrics.

I had a question like this two or three months ago, but the answered don't help me.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4188872/analysis-matrix-exponential-infimum-and-limit

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko This was also my first idea, but it seems that the infimum is taken over $z\in\mathbb Z^n\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Can you be clear about the quantifiers in your question? Is $X$ a fixed matrix? Is your hypothesis that *for all* $B\in M_n(\mathbb R)$, $f(e^XB,z)=0$ if and only if $z=0$? And the same quantifiers on the conclusion?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas $X$ is an any matrix and $B$ is a full rank matrix. In my hypothesis, when $f(e^XB, z) = 0 \iff z = 0$ (1) implies that the matrix $X$ converges to zero. So my question is if the equality that I've written is true for all $B$ and $z$ with the hypothesis (1). But I think that don't need used it (1) for prove my question.

Comment: @MatthewDaws yes, I've tried to get a solution one month ago on mathexchange, but anybody could help me. And my friend told me that this question is more appropriate here. So I put here this question. I am a beginning reasearch and don't use internet too much. So I didn't know this site some years ago.